# Use cookie-free domains in Opencart - YSlow recommendation

Tags: performance, cookies, pagespeed, yslow

I'm trying to optimize my website speed according to Google Speed Test and GTMetrix YSlow. One of the recommendation is to "use cookie-free domains", there are 12 components that are not cookie-free.

The 12 components are images and some CSS and JS files.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: which is actual version of opencart you have. and what is your Google Speed Test score ?

Comment: @MujahidBhoraniya Im using Opencart 3.0.2.0 , I'm using GTMetrix speed test

Comment: What is your GTmatrix website score?

Comment: Otherwise send me your website URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie free domains relates to having domains that send a cookie with every request.

Say for example you serve all of your images from your main domain and your main domain has cookies on it.

Every one of those images will have a cookie sent with the request for the file, which the server ignores anyway.

This is completely unnecessary traffic as the cookie serves no purpose.

To fix this either use a cookie free CDN or set up a sub domain on your server that has no cookies.

Then serve all of your static assets such as fonts, images, JS and CSS from this sub domain / CDN.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So every file have a cookies attached to it with every request ? Can I control which files have cookies ? The only solution is to move those files to a new domain or CDN ? How can I know which files should be cookie free ?

Comment: I said in my answer - **all static files** should be cookie free - fonts, images, JS and CSS. The only solution is to serve from a new domain - so CDN or sub domain as your main domain will send cookie requests with every request and there is no (reasonable) way of doing anything different. - my answer covered it all bud :-P

Answer (score 0):

**[100% Working]**

One of my website I installed **NitroPack IO - Performance & SEO Booster** Extension.

**[Download Free Extension Here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=36373&filter_license=0&page=3)**

Before install Extension my website score in **Mobile : 27 Desktop : 32**

After install Extension score in **Mobile : 98 Desktop : 99**

I really appreciate this extension and his review is almost very good.

Comment: I'm not asking for extensions. Thank you